# how to make bar fixed correctly?

Tags: html, css

i have to problems ..
first : i made a login page , and made the login tab fixed at the top , and made the sign up window absolute then when i scroll down the sign up window goes over the login bar

the second one : 
i resized the username and password box , and made them bigger the problem is the box becomes bigger but the words i write in them still in there regular size .

my code :

html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Taabe3</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body background="img/background.jpg" id="background">
<img src="img/bar.png" id="bar">
<div class="login_form">
<div  id="username">

<form>
<p><span>UserName:</span>
<input name="UserName" type="text" size="0" id="box1" >
</p>
</form>
</div>


<div class="login_form" id="pass"><form>
<p><span>Password:</span>
<input  name="lastname" type="password" id="box2">
</p>
</form>
</div>
<a href="" id="link" >
<div id="login"  >Login</div>
</a>

<div id="sbackground">
</div>

<div id="sign up">

<form>
<p><span id="text6"><strong>UserName:</strong></span>
<input name="UserName" type="text" size="0" id="box6" >
</p>
</form>


<form>
<p><span id="text5"><strong>Email:</strong></span>
<input name="Email" type="text" size="0" id="box5" >
</p>
</form>

<form>
<p><span id="text4"><strong>Password:</strong></span>
<input name="Password" type="password" size="0" id="box4" >
</p>
</form>

<form>
<p ><span id="text3" ><strong>Confirm Password:</strong></span>
<input name="Password" type="Password" size="0" id="box3" >
</p>
</form>

<a href="" id="link" >
<div id="signup"  ><p id="stext">Sign Up<p></div>
</a>


<img src="img/Untitled-1.png" width="640" height="35"  id="line"/> </div>

<img src="img/login_with_facebook.png" width="602" height="60" id="facebook"/>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
    #pass{
position: fixed;
top: 22px;
left: 963px;
right: 10%;
width: 280px;
height: 62px;
border-radius: 20px;
font-family: corbel;
    }

    #username{
position:fixed;
top: 23px;
left: 709px;
right: 10%;
width: 280px;
height: 61px;
font-family: corbel;
border:medium;
border-color:black;

    }

    #background{
height: 1000px;
    }

    #button{
position: fixed;
left: 1170px;
top: 40px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:corbel;
}

    #loginform{position:fixed;left:100px}

    #bar{
position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:black;
    border:solid 2px;
    border-color:#09F
    }

    #login{
    position: fixed;
    top: 38px;
    left: 1202px;
    width: 63px;
    height: 23px;
    background-color: #2799b6;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: corbel;
    border-radius:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:15px;
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transition:    opacity .5s;
    -o-transition:      opacity .5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition:         opacity .5s;

    }

    #link{text-decoration:none}

    #login:hover{
    opacity:0.7;
   -moz-transition:    opacity .5s;
   -o-transition:      opacity .5s;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
   transition:         opacity .5s;
   }

   #box1{border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
   border-radius:20px;
    height:20px;
    }

   #box2{border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
   border-radius:20px;
    height:20px;

    }

   #box1:focus {
   border: 2px solid #5ad3de;
outline:none;
    }

   #box2:focus {
border: 2px solid #5ad3de;
outline:none;

    }

    #sbackground{background-color:white;
    height:550px;
    width:350px;
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    right:100px;
    border-radius:20px;
    opacity:0.7;

    }

    #box3{border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
    border-radius:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:508px;
    right:150px;
    height:30px;
    width:250px
    }
    #text3{position:absolute;
    top:478px;
    right:160px;
    font-family:corbel;
    color: #2799B6;
    font-size:20px
            }

            #box3:focus {
border: 2px solid #5ad3de;
outline:none;}

            #box4{border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
    border-radius:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:429px;
    right:150px;
    height:30px;
    width:250px
    }
    #box4:focus {
border: 2px solid #5ad3de;
outline:none;}
    #text4{position:absolute;
    top:399px;
    right:160px;
    font-family:corbel;
    color: #2799B6;
    font-size:20px
             }


             #box5{border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
    border-radius:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:350px;
    right:150px;
    height:30px;
    width:250px

    }
    #box5:focus {
              border: 2px solid #5ad3de;
outline:none;}
    #text5{position:absolute;
    top:320px;
    right:160px;
    font-family:corbel;
    color: #2799B6;
    font-size:20px
            }


            #box6{border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
    border-radius:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:270px;
    right:150px;
    height:30px;
    width:250px
    }
    #box6:focus {
border: 2px solid #5ad3de;
outline:none;}
          #text6{position:absolute;
    top:240px;
    right:160px;
    font-family:corbel;
    color: #2799B6;
    font-size:20px
            }

            #signup{
             position: absolute;
            top: 580px;
           right: 230px;
           width: 110px;
            height: 40px;
             background-color: #2799b6;
            text-align: center;
              font-family: corbel;
                  border-radius:20px;
               color:#FFF;
           font-size:19px;
            opacity:1;
            -moz-transition:    opacity .5s;
            -o-transition:      opacity .5s;
               -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
               transition:         opacity .5s;

                }
                #stext{position:absolute;top:-10px;
                 left: 26px;}

                  #link{text-decoration:none}

                 #signup:hover{
                opacity:0.7;
                -moz-transition:    opacity .5s;
                -o-transition:      opacity .5s;
                    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
                    transition:         opacity .5s;
                       }


                  #line{position: absolute;
               top: 640px;
                right: 212px;
                width:150px}

                  #facebook{
             position: absolute;
         top: 665px;
          right: 19px;
opacity: 1;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s;
-o-transition: opacity .5s;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
transition: opacity .5s;
width: 506px;
height: 74px;

        }
#facebook:hover{
         opacity:0.7;
      -moz-transition:    opacity .5s;
     -o-transition:      opacity .5s;
     -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
      transition:         opacity .5s;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

for the stacking order (like layers in photoshop for example) - if you don't set a z-index, what ever is rendered last to page will be the previous element when absolutely positioned. have a look at the [z-index css property](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index) - so say set

```
#bar{
  z-index:5;
}

#login-form{
  z-index:4;
}
```

you will need to look at your HTML hard though as i'm not sure you understand how div's and form elements work; divs allow you to contain multiple elements (they are containers), and you need to nest all form elements within one form tag if you wish to make any sensible use of them. Also check out the difference between fixed, absolute and relative positioning [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Comment: thanks it wroked , but did you know the solution for the second problem,
and when i set the z-index the username and password disappear.